# Continuous WebJob/Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to have a block of code, which is being executed continuously and infinitely. This code grab data from suite of remote resources to update data in my db. When all remote resources are called I need to start to do it from zero and this process is infinity. I don't need any triggers etc, just infinity look like:

```
while(true)
{
   // call remote resources and update my db
}
```

nothing more. Which type of Azure application should I select? I use .NET Core, therefore I look at Azure Functions. So, only durable (orchestration) function does not have any triggers to call, but seems this is not a singleton function (of course, I need singleton).

Comment: This seems like a continuous webjob (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs).   Do look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose what you want is the continuous webjob, it supports the .net core and singleton.

Further information about how to deploy .net core app as webjob, you could refer to this tutorial: [WebJobs as .NET Core console apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs#webjobs-as-net-core-console-apps). You could just publish your block code like below.

[image]

[image]

As for the singleton property, you could use a `settings.job` file to implement it, in the settings.job file, add `is_singleton` it will only run the WebJobs on a single instance when scaled out.

You could refer to this wiki:[settings.job reference](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#settingsjob-reference).